# datatable displaying differently on two views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, coffeescript

I have a Rails app based the railsapp project "Startup Prelaunch Signup Site"

I am trying to replicate a datatable from the prebuilt pages onto one I wrote and the datatable on my page is missing the pagination and search box that appear on the prebuilt page.

Although the haml declaration for the datatable is identical in the two views, the html it produces is different. The html from my view is missing the following;

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid">
<div class="row">
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I can post more code if it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend found the mistake in my code that was causing this problem.  For the benefit 
anyone having a similar problem here is what fixed it;

The datatable in my view had 7 th (table headers) defined and only 5 tds (table data).  Even though the table displayed ok, except for the extra headers, it confused the tableData java script enough to not work.